# How to connect 2 home routers to connect 2 separate networks?

Tags: networking, router, wireless-router, home-networking, subnet

I don't know if it's a silly question, but I'm not very good at networking. So please help me out.

I have a Netgear WNDR4500, and I configured my PCs and virtual machines setting the WNDR4500 (192.168.1.1) as their default gateway. Recently I bought a Netgear R6300, and I'm thinking to put this router (192.168.2.1) as the default gateway of some PCs and VMs. So, I'll be having two different networks, right?

Both routers have 1 WAN port and 4 LAN ports, and I have my broadband connection in the WAN port of the first one. Now I want these two networks to be connected so that the PCs in one network can communicate with the PCs in the other network. So, how do I connect the two routers to make this happen?

Comment: As Jishnu says, you can do it but you will need to change the second LAN IP range to fall within the range of the first router to allow the whole network to communicate. If your subnets are different then they won't be able to communicate without more complex routing rules that your routers might not be able to do as they are soho devices not designed to be able to manage such routing requests.

Comment: @BigChris: Cascading is not my intention.

Comment: @NerotheZero What is the reasoning behind having two separate networks? If you want all devices to see and communicate with each other, you might as well have them all on the same network. First router would take care of NAT, DHCP, etc and the second would just work as a wireless access point and switch. You will not be performing double NAT etc.

Comment: Can you be more precise about your broadband connection, what type it is, and how it works? What device does it come from? Does that device have any routing capabilities? Does it have more than one port?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: To be honest, I don't have a clear idea. It's something like a PPPoE connection which comes through a CAT5 from my ISP. If its connected to my PC, I need to dial and enter my credentials, but when it's connected to the router's WAN port, the routers handles the dialing.

Comment: @VivekThomas: Just experimentation & learning about how routers connects different networks, and how my tcp packets are routed among them. You might suggest a network simulator like TCP Trace, but still I didn't find a way to connect the two routers in that simulator. I have a software to develop which requires a clear understanding about tcp packet routing between separate (but connected) networks.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible. We are using at out work place. Our setup is

1. Both the routers connected via LAN
2. Static local IP for both the routers, 10.1.1.1 for first and 10.1.1.2 for the second.
3. DHCP server enabled only in one.
4. Configured operation mode as Gateway in one.

Now you should be able to access devices in both the networks. If you want a specific Internet connection for a device, you can change Gateway in the connection configuration to x.x.x.1 or x.x.x.2 to select the router.

Comment: What you are suggesting is Cascading-Routers. I'm not talking about cascading, putting one router under the other.